# Django unable to open database file using mysql

Tags: django

I'm a newbie in django so as python

I just succesfully configured my first django site over an apache server, then I configured it to work with mysql database editing the settings.py file and running the following command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I started playing a bit with the admin but occasionally when making get or post requests I get the following message **OperationalError at "/some/route" unable to open database file**

If I refresh the page loads fine, but if i keep refreshing any page in the admin the error shows up, so it's a random thing.

For what I've searched this is an issue related with sqlite, but I'm using mysql.

My database config in settings.py is the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'simulation',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': ''
    }
}
```

I tried to specify hosts "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" but the result was the same.

It's really important for me find a solution that uses mysql as database engine.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: can you add another setting `PORT: ''` in `default` and try ?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem that you have right here, in my instance it seemed like my settings.py file was cached on the server. Once I deleted the .pyc files it started working fine.

Also, what happens if you change your database to sqlite? It might be worth checking that your mysql database isn't playing up instead of django.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Django/Mysql/WSGI/Apache setup. Similar to Serakiel, I think that the problem stemmed from server caching. Restarting apache fixed the problem for me.